# Error while creating a new york city map with get_map Function

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have been trying to plot a map of locations of different types of buildings that consume natural gas in the New York city

I tried to download the map of New York with `get_map` function

```
map <- get_map(location ="New York", maptype = "terrain",
         source='google',color='color')
```

When I try this I keep getting this error

> Error in data.frame(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

How do I retify this error?

I also tried to use latitude and longitude locations doesn't seem to work either

Comment: code works fine for me.

Comment: Are your packages up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem for a long time. Drove me nuts. Sometimes it worked by itself, sometimes it didn't. Even after updating all the packages. I was using `rmarkdown` with caching enabled.

I think I found the issue. It is due to [caching](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/48) in the hidden object `.GeocodedInformation`.

Now I placed this before my code and I don't see the error anymore:

```
if (exists('.GeocodedInformation')) rm(.GeocodedInformation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my R and even using the line if

```
(exists('.GeocodedInformation')) rm(.GeocodedInformation)
```

it didn't work.

However, the solution to this problem was to run immediately before of the Knitr, the chunk of the getmap.